# Adding new characters to beginning and end of each line in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, foreach, character

I have a textbox with multiline enabled, and want to add a string at the beginning and end of
each line, so every line would be changed to

```
a + line + b
```

Now I know it has to do with a foreach loop, but don't know how to write it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the [`Lines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property is probably the one you want. Three options:

```
string[] lines = textBox.Lines;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
     lines[i] = a + lines[i] + b;
}
textBox.Lines = lines;
```

Or:

```
textBox.Lines = Array.ConvertAll(textBox.Lines, line => a + line + b);
```

Or:

```
textBox.Lines = textBox.Lines
                       .Select(line => a + line + b)
                       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a replace on the entire text:

```
text = a + text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, b + Environment.NewLine + a) + b;
```

Comment: Instead of Enviroment.NewLine, can I use "\r\n"?
Or at least, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @SharkRetriever: The `NewLine` property is the character combination used on the current system. If it's a Windows system, it's `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned foreach, here's another way.

```
var newLines = new List<string>(textBox1.Lines.Length);

foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
   newLines.Add(a + line + b);

textBox1.Lines = newLines.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i use to add the characters a and b to the beginning and the end to a string that contains a bunch of lines :

```
     public string Script;
     string[] lines = Script.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' });
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        lines[i] = a + lines[i] + b;
                        if (!lines[i].Equals("\"\"+"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
                            Result += lines[i]+"\n";
                        }
                    }
```